# My wallet showing nothing in it

Tags: wallet

Explorer showing me this.

https://explorer.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io/en/address.html?address=addr_test1vp465rg9nm7x3th67nfsccuav25ffvjk3wr5upk57k3ec9gadwcjp

But if i check my wallet balance directly from the shell it is showing me nothing in it.

```
cardano-cli query utxo --address addr_test1vp465rg9nm7x3th67nfsccuav25ffvjk3wr5upk57k3ec9gadwcjp --testnet-magic 1097911063 --cardano-mode
                           TxHash                                 TxIx        Amount
```

---

Comment: Is the node fully synced? The CLI will show zero balance if the transaction that created the paid to that added has not been downloaded yet.

Comment: How do i know if the node is fully synced or not? I can see that this is going on `eb4cde7e343e83820321069f5df4b3dbf705feef741f19270a2b56404f43aa3a at slot 44463043
[dk-Latit:cardano.node.ChainDB:Notice:142] [2022-02-15 08:02:03.05 UTC] Chain extended, new tip: b1c0fe52e6fac43668ac485dd922b57d160ee999a0d4e327a105d6a4422098df at slot 44463323
[dk-Latit:cardano.node.ChainDB:Notice:142] [2022-02-15 08:02:04.34 UTC] Chain extended, new tip: 4ff762c7491523fadf6406ca66325f8ac43f000f444ed07f8656156149e4da78 at slot 44463606
[dk-Latit:cardano.node.ChainDB:Notic`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `cardano-cli query tip` command to check if the node is synced, a `syncProgress` with the percentage value will appear there.

You will need your node to be synced to at least 4 days ago (Epoch 186, Block 3312024), when your transaction in the testnet took place. Otherwise it could be that what you are seeing is the status of your wallet in an older point in time.

Comment: This is what i am getting `cardano-cli query tip syncProgress
Invalid argument `syncProgress'

Usage: cardano-cli query tip 
            [ --shelley-mode
            | --byron-mode [--epoch-slots NATURAL]
            | --cardano-mode [--epoch-slots NATURAL]
            ]
            (--mainnet | --testnet-magic NATURAL)
            [--out-file FILE]

  Get the node's current tip (slot no, hash, block no)`

Comment: You don't have to run `cardano-cli query tip syncProgress`, only `cardano-cli query tip`. The `syncProgress`will be part of the output in your terminal.

Comment: `cardano-cli query tip --cardano-mode --testnet-magic 1097911063
` This is what worked